# On page load, display static images at the same time vue dynamically loaded images

Tags: html, image, dom, vue.js, browser

On my working project, the frontend is not entirely an SPA, as well not defining all the components in the template engine, but image loading is inconsistent between the document and vue. I am having trouble coming up with an appropriate solution with loading the document images when the vue components are loading and displaying.

We need to display everything at once when vue displays components.

One solution I can think of is to apply the source links in `data-src` in all the `img` elements. When vue is ready to display the components, the value from `data-src` would be applied to the `src` attribute and the browser starts to download the image files.

But there are other issues with CSS loading images as well and I'm not sure how I would control the loading there. I'm assuming I would have to define outside of CSS and use JS for this?

2 other solutions I can think of is to just hide the page until vue has completed rendering, but this would increase the time to see the page. Or use placeholder media in place of loading photos.

Comment: Maybe  [v-cloak](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak) can help. **Edit**: I just glanced the question, now I see that it's more speciffic than just **v-cloak**

Comment: yes, I'm using v-cloak for the vue template variables, but this is different regarding the image loading. I'm not sure if my idea will solve my issue though